# Fill an array with descending values

Tags: java, arrays

Trying to find the easiest way to fill an array with some values starting at 23 in descending order. I have the code below but not getting the result i am looking for:

```
int[] arr = new int[8];
int i = 24;
Arrays.fill(arr, --i);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
```

output now

```
[23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23]
```

expected

```
[23, 22, 21, 20, 19, 18, 17, 16]
```

How to fill an array easily and get the expected output, if possible without a for/while loop?

Comment: I'm going to ask the obvious: What's the problem with using an explicit loop (rather than an implicit one that a standard library function will use under the hood)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not simply use a for loop?

```
for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
    arr[j] = i;
    i--;
}
```

You can also use the Arrays.setAll function

```
Arrays.setAll(arr, (index) -> i - index);
```

By the way, Arrays.fill will fill the all array with the given value, so that's why you're getting `[23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23, 23]`.

Answer (score 1):

You could use Streams :

```
IntStream.iterate(23, i -> i - 1)
            .limit(8)
            .toArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to write a for loop in descending order to complete and display the array.